# phpmyadmin shows black screen

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem that bothers me a lot. When I try to access phpmyadmin the screen becomes black, I have to update the page every time so that it becomes normal again.

What is amazing is that I have this problem on my local machine is also server side, it means that the problem does not necessarily concern the installed version.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Which browser and which phpMyAdmin theme?

Comment: thanx for the comment ! I changed the browser and everything works fine !